# update android manifest using React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, expo

I would like to add this line to the android manifest, I am using React Native Expo.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

to the application tag.

I have tried in the app.json under

```
android.usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

But i receive an error this error

```
 • Field: android - should NOT have additional property 'usesCleartextTraffic'.
```